# install python project using PIP

Tags: python, pypi

I've developed a chatbot project and this is the structure of its folder:

```
chatbot1:
     __init__.py
     __pycache__
     build
     chatbot_script.egg-info
     dist
     MANIFEST.in 
     package_data.dat
     README.rst
     setup.cfg
     setup.py
     stanford-postagger-full-2015-04-20
     main_chatbot.py
     Female_chatbot.py
     Male_chatbot.py
     arabic_const.py
     normalize.py
     stem_const.py
     stemming.py
```

and this is the setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from codecs import open
from os import path

here = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
with open(path.join(here, 'README.rst'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
long_description = f.read()
setup(name='chatbot_script',
      version='1.2.0',
      description='is a simple chatbot_script that uses simple matching ',
      long_description=long_description, 
      url='https://github.com/pypi/chatbot_script',license='MIT', classifiers=   
      ['Development Status :: 3 - Alpha','Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Build Tools',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',],
      keywords='sample setuptools development',
      packages=find_packages(),
      install_requires=['peppercorn'],
      extras_require={
             'dev': ['check-manifest'],
             'test': ['coverage'],},
       package_data={
             'sample': ['package_data.dat'],},
       entry_points={
             'console_scripts': [
             'sample=sample:main',],},)
```

I successfully upload the chatbot_script to PyPi and testPyPi. But when I download it there are only these files:

```
chatbot_script-1.2.0:
    chatbot_script.egg-info
    PKG-INFO
    README.rst
    setup.cfg
    setup.py
```

Why I can't upload the other files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main files should go in a wrapper folder

and in your MANIFEST.in you can include/exlude files

For example

File Structure:

```
chatbot1:
    MANIFEST.in 
    setup.cfg
    setup.py
    README.rst
    chatbot1:
        <package files>
```

MANIFEST.in

```
recursive-include chatbot1 .*
graft chatbot1
prune chatbot1/unwanted_files
```

Comment: what is a wrapper folder? actually i want to install the python package in a django project in a virtual environment

Comment: You should not put the dist utils files (setup.py, etc) in your main package. The package shld be on the same folder level as your setup.py script

Comment: how to put the file in a wrapper folder?

Comment: You just need to edit the file structure like i suggested in my answer. Make another folder called chatbox1 (within your current chatbot1 folder ) and move all the package files in there, leaving out all the setuptools related files were they are. And edit you manifest file accordingly.

Comment: No problem. You can accept the solution then. Cheers